# How are objects stored within a Kinetic.Layer within Kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am currently creating a grid of Triangles using a for loop using a predetermined set of coordinates in a separate array.

Like so:

```
        function createTri(x, y, z, a) {
            var tri = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
                id: a,
                x: x,
                y: y,
                sides: 3,
                radius: 15,
                rotation: z,
                fillRed: 17,
                fillGreen: 17,
                fillBlue: 17,
                closed: true,
                shadowColor: '#5febff',
                shadowBlur: 5,
                shadowOpacity: 0.18
            });

            layer.add(tri);

        }

        for (var i = 0; i < pax.length; i++){
            for (var j = 0; j < pax[i].length; j++){
                createTri(pax[i][j][0],pax[i][j][1],pax[i][j][2],(i+'')+(j+''));
            };
        }
```

However when I try to return a `console.log()` of a specfic id from the layer container, I am getting nothing but code instead of an id number.

Im not entirely sure if Im calling it wrong for Kinetic, or calling it wrong in general.

So I guess I need to know what the normal way to call the object by the id property would be, or how to properly call it from a Kinetic.Layer.

Edit: to expound, how im trying to call it is defined within the Kinetic documentation as `node.find('selector);`, so when attempting to find by id, I am trying to log to the console: `console.log(layer.find('#1674'));` However when I do this, the console logs a prototype object with all possible associated functions instead of the object Im trying to call.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the source of your problem is that the id of your triangle object is not what you expect it to be.

You should see something like this (in Chrome):

```
[Kinetic.RegularPolygon, each: function, toArray: function, _init: function, _clearCache: function, _getCache: function…]
```

Are you seeing this?

```
[each: function, toArray: function, _init: function, _clearCache: function, _getCache: function…]
```

That's what I get when I provide a invalid id to the layer's `find` method.

Here's a fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/Tn5bm/

Comment: That is exactly what I am getting. My id Im setting should be a string and not a value... but I could be wrong. Im setting the string as `(i+'')+(j+'')` which SHOULD change it into a string instead of a value. Also to verify that Im selecting a valid id, Im console logging all the ids generated when a triangle is generated. So Im picking one from what I see.

Comment: @JSArrakis I see. What's the scope of your layer object? Have you verified that the shapes are being added to the node you're checking (e.g. `node.getChildren().length`)? You can also run `find` on your Kinetic stage object and it should return the object if it's in a node that you're not expecting. As an aside, watch out for id conflicts such as `i=1,j=11` and `i=11,j=1`.

Comment: Yep I ran a `layer.children.length` and got back 500 something. Which, Im assuming is the correct number, but now I might have to actually count each triangle on the visible canvas to be sure. The question about the scope though... that Im not entirely sure. Also good catch with that but Ive noticed for the id naming that it ends up being i=01, j=11 or i=11, j=01 so there wont be much issue there. Also, im unsure of how searching for a specific id within the stage container will give me the correct parent of the node?

Comment: Also, if it helps at all, here is my current github of the project so you can see my current code: https://github.com/JSArrakis/Paradigm-Engineering/blob/master/Arrakis.html

Comment: @JSArrakis Have you tried `console.log(layer.getChildren()[0].getAttr('id'))`?

Comment: Yep, and it brings back undefined.